# Question about installing and configuring Gerrit in an on-premise environment on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gerrit, on-premises-instances

I am experiencing an issue while setting up Gerrit for testing purposes in an on-premise environment on Ubuntu.

I followed the official documentation and various articles to install Gerrit and was able to access it. I chose the development_become_any_account authentication method for testing purposes and created a Gerrit account. I created a repository as shown in "Image 1" to proceed with source code reviews.

I used Git to commit and push a Java project file that I created, but even though the commit and push were successful, I cannot see the uploaded source code in the repository.

When I check the Gerrit documentation on Google, it mentions the "Browse" section indicated in "Image 1," and it should be possible to access the repository and view the source code. However, in the Gerrit instance I created, I cannot see anything.

I have tried completely uninstalling Gerrit and reinstalling it, but the same issue persists. I would appreciate any help or guidance from those familiar with setting up Gerrit in an on-premise environment. Please assist me.

"Image 2" and "Image 3" are screenshots of the installation options I selected during the Gerrit setup.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvo2u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPHvG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K7CC.png)

Answer (score -1):

The issue has been resolved. When installing Gerrit in an on-premise environment, it is necessary to install additional plugins in order to use Gerrit properly.

Comment: What additional plugins?

Comment: To install Gerrit in an on-premise environment, you will need the installation file in the form of a JAR file. After downloading the installation file and running it, you will be prompted to enter various values in the terminal during the installation process. At the final stage of the installation, you will encounter a question asking whether you want to install several plugins (Y/N). It is shown as "Install plugin~" like the third picture in the article.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).